# asp - mysql not updating records

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

```
Dim prestaDB 
prestaDB = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=mysql50-64.wc1;PORT=3306;DATABASE=example_db;USER=example_user;PASSWORD=example_password;OPTION=3;" 
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
conn.open prestaDB 
conn.execute("update ps_product set quantity = " & sSeg(4) & " where reference = '%" & sSeg(0) &"%'")
```

The rest of the code sets:

```
sSeg(4) = 5
sSeg(0) = "N540"
```

N540 is a valid reference in my db

When this is executed, it gives no errors yet the quantity does not update to be 5.

The server is running MySQL 5

**Any ideas what is going wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the

```
where reference = '%....
```

to
`where reference like '%`